# Macrium Reflect Installation failure

Tags: ssd, windows-installer, macrium

I'm trying to install Macrium Reflect Home edition on a dell 8700 with SSD (no spinning media).  All proceeds as expected until I launch the setup proper, at which point it barfs with:

[Macium install fail](https://www.dropbox.com/s/t6thp8vbsc7lzwe/Screenshot%202020-08-05%2016.18.26.png?raw=1)

The [install log](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jfm0d0e5l8ozyhf/Reflect_Install.log?dl=0) seems to report some cosmetic inconsistencies in the UI before it errors out.

The final bit of the log is:

```
=== Logging stopped: 5/08/2020  16:18:57 ===
MSI (c) (B4:E8) [16:18:57:510]: Note: 1: 1708 
MSI (c) (B4:E8) [16:18:57:510]: Product: Macrium Reflect Free Edition -- Installation failed.

MSI (c) (B4:E8) [16:18:57:511]: Windows Installer installed the product. Product Name: Macrium Reflect Free Edition. Product Version: 7.2.4971. Product Language: 1033. Manufacturer: Paramount Software (UK) Ltd.. Installation success or error status: 1603.

MSI (c) (B4:E8) [16:18:57:512]: Grabbed execution mutex.
MSI (c) (B4:E8) [16:18:57:512]: Cleaning up uninstalled install packages, if any exist
MSI (c) (B4:E8) [16:18:57:513]: MainEngineThread is returning 1603
=== Verbose logging stopped: 5/08/2020  16:18:57 ===
```

Comment: Your installer is corrupt

Comment: I have a D8700 with ssd and Macrium Reflect Free (home) installed just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, check and remove from the Registry and file system any left-over bits from the failed installation.

Second, run the installation as *Administrator*.

If that fails, check that the Window temp folder has sufficient permissions and free space:

- Press <kbd>Windows</kbd>, type %temp%, and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to open the default temporary folder.
- Try to delete most folders and files in *Temp* (if a particular file is in use, Windows will prevent that item's removal).
- Right-click the *Temp* folder and select *Properties*.
- On the Security tab, check that you, the System and Administrators have full control; if not click *Edit* and add them in.

Comment: Success! I'm assuming it was the stuff in the registry left over from the previous unsuccessful installation, as everything else looked OK and didn't need attention.  Many thanks.

Comment: Glad it worked!